# Delete the repeated links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, thumbnails

I have a question regarding some JavaScript, there is a big picture and the thumbnails, my JavaScript function changes the link of the big picture taking it from a thumbnail, and it works fine, but also I have a highslide, that works for a big picture, when the big picture is clicked, its real size is shown in a highslide, but I have a little problem, when I change the link of a big picture, it automatically comes two links of this picture, the one in a big picture and the other in a thumbnail, so I need to be deleted the other link in a thumbnail after I click on it, so this is my script for now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imagePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var newImg = new Image;
    newImg.onload = function(){
        $('#big_picture2').hide();
        $('#big_picture2').attr('src', imagePath);
        $('.product_image_large').attr('href', imagePath);
        $('#big_picture2').fadeIn('slow');
    };
    newImg.src = imagePath;
    });
});
```

Comment: Since you appear to be using jQuery, I've added that tag (replacing "repeated"), so people who focus on jQuery more than JavaScript will see it.

Comment: And what is your question or problem?

Comment: @reporter i want to be deleted the repeated links in a thumbnails, since i use the highslide, the highslide of the pictures will be repeated

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thx just didn't pay attention :)

Comment: So you click on a thumbnail and that image replaces the one in the big picture? This causes the link to duplicate so you need to remove it from the clicked thumbnail. What happens when you click a second thumbnail? Presumably the link needs to be added to the first thumbnail again. Is that right?

Comment: @lnrbob it changes the link of the big picture too, no difference whether it second time or third, and yes the other stuff exactly like this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but think this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
//add big picture link to active thumbnail
$('.image.active').attr('href',$('#big_picture2').attr('src')).removeClass('active');
//set new active thumbnail
$(this).addClass('.active');
    var imagePath = $(this).attr("href");
//remove this href
$(this).removeAttr('href');
    var newImg = new Image;
    newImg.onload = function(){
        $('#big_picture2').hide();
        $('#big_picture2').attr('src', imagePath);
        $('.product_image_large').attr('href', imagePath);
        $('#big_picture2').fadeIn('slow');
    };
    newImg.src = imagePath;
    });
});
```